# Dropdown is not aligned with other input boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I based on this angular [component](https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiselect-checkbox-dropdown?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fmulti-select-dropdown%2Fmulti-select-dropdown.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

I have an html with a few input boxes. The first input can be replaced with a multi-select dropdown.

But when the dropdown appears, it's not aligned with its sibling input boxes.

How can I fix this ad-hock?

HTML:

```
        <div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
            <label for="cidList">Customer ID <a (click)="switch_cid()" class="smalltext">{{cid_choice}}</a><br>
            <input *ngIf="manual_cid" type="text" [className]="customer_id_error ? 'errorElement' : 'inputElement'" formControlName="cidList" name="cidList">
            <a *ngIf="!manual_cid"><br></a>
            <a *ngIf="!manual_cid" [className]="customer_id_error ? 'errorElement' : 'inputElement'" name="cidList" class="inputElement" formControlName="cidList" id="cidList">
                <app-multi-select-dropdown 
                    [myList]="customer_list"
                    (shareCheckedList)="shareCheckedList($event)" 
                    (shareIndividualCheckedList)="shareIndividualCheckedList($event)">
                </app-multi-select-dropdown>
            </a>
            <span class="error_text" *ngIf=customer_id_error>Needs a valid CID</span></label>
        </div>
        <div class="label-input-block top-centre-form">
            <label for="fromDaysAgo">From Days Ago</label><br>
            <input type="text" [className]="from_lookback_error ? 'smallErrorElement' : 'smallInputElement'" formControlName="fromDaysAgo" name="fromDaysAgo"><br>
            <span class="error_text" *ngIf=from_lookback_error>Must be number <= 90</span>
        </div>
```

[image]

vs.

[image]

Comment: your html doesn't match your picture. also, why the heck would you put an input box inside a label?

Comment: You have tagged this CSS but provided none  Perhaps enhance your question with more details

Comment: Is the space gone without the hidden input and anchor tag for Customer Id? Also since this is a different input type than the others I would check for a global styling somewhere maybe?

Comment: @DCR It's not an input, it's a button. How would you change this? was without it it even goes worse

Comment: @GotStu I checked but found nothing specific. Any ad-hock css that can help?

Comment: Always peel back the layers. What is different between the two. I suggest go to a jsFiddle which sets the stage for minimal introduction of things that go wrong. Take the ngif and Anugular out of the complexity and put in direct html with you existing stylings. You will find answer I feel.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the input tag into the label tags. Also checking 
 tag. Hope it helps.